# Inserir dados em uma tabela a partir de outras 4

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho esse código para inserir dados no banco, eu gostaria de inserir dados de 4 tabelas em uma só. Porém consecutivamente, eu tentei desse modo só que ele adiciona os mesmos dados para as 3 ultimas tabelas e somente muda os dados do primeiro select. Alguém saberia me ajudar?

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','teste2');
$link->set_charset("utf8");

$query = "SELECT * from review_store";
$select = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){

$review_store= array(
$review_id_store = 'review_id_store'=>$row['review_id'],
$store_id_store = 'store_id_store'=>$row['store_id']//REVIEW_STORE
);


$queryx = "SELECT * from review_entity_summary";
$selectx = mysqli_query($link, $queryx);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectx);

 $review_sumary= array(
$primary_id = 'primary_id'=>$row['primary_id'],
$entity_pk_value_summary = 'entity_pk_value_summary'=>$row['entity_pk_value'],
$entity_type = 'entity_type'=>$row['entity_type'],
$reviews_count = 'reviews_count'=>$row['reviews_count'],
$rating_summary = 'rating_summary'=>$row['rating_summary'],
$store_id_summary = 'store_id_summary'=>$row['store_id']//REVIEW_ENTITY_SUMMARY
);


$querys = "SELECT * from review_detail";
$selects = mysqli_query($link, $querys);


$row = mysqli_fetch_array($selects);

 $review_det= array(
$id = 'detail_id'=>$row['detail_id'],
$review_id = 'review_id_detail'=>$row['review_id'],
$store_id_detail = 'store_id_detail'=>$row['store_id'],
$title = 'title'=>$row['title'],
$detail = 'detail'=>$row['detail'],
$nickname = 'nickname'=>$row['nickname'],
$customer_id = 'customer_id'=>$row['customer_id']//REVIEW_DETAIL
);

$querya = "SELECT * from review";
$selecta = mysqli_query($link, $querya);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($selecta);

$review = array(
$review_id = 'review_id'=>$row['review_id'],
$criadoem = 'criadoem'=>$row['created_at'],
$entity_id = 'entity_id'=>$row['entity_id'],
$entity_pk_value = 'entity_pk_value'=>$row['entity_pk_value'],
$status_id = 'status_id'=>$row['status_id']//REVIEW
);

print_r(array($review_store, $review_sumary, $review_det, $review)); 

$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$query = "INSERT INTO comentproduto (`primary_id`, `entity_pk_value_summary`, `entity_type`, `reviews_count`, `rating_summary`, `store_id_summary`, `review_id_store`, `store_id_store`, `detail_id`, `review_id_detail`, `store_id_detail`, `title`, `detail`, `nickname`, `customer_id`, `review_id`, `created_at`, `entity_id`, `entity_pk_value`, `status_id`) VALUES ('".$review_store[$review_id_store]."', '".$review_store[$store_id_store]."', '".$review_sumary[$primary_id]."', '".$review_sumary[$entity_pk_value_summary]."', '".$review_sumary[$entity_type]."', '".$review_sumary[$reviews_count]."', '".$review_sumary[$rating_summary]."', '".$review_sumary[$store_id_summary]."', '".$review_det['detail_id']."', '".$review_det[$review_id]."', '".$review_det[$store_id_detail]."', '".$review_det['title']."', '".$review_det['detail']."', '".$review_det['nickname']."', '".$review_det['customer_id']."', '".$review['review_id']."', '".$review['criadoem']."', '".$review['entity_id']."', '".$review['entity_pk_value']."', '".$review['status_id']."')";
$connection->query($query);
}
```

**Como está sendo salvo**

**Primeiro "giro"**

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [review_id_store] => 7 //SOMENTE ESSES VALOR É ALTERADO
        [store_id_store] => 0 //SOMENTE ESSES VALOR É ALTERADO
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [primary_id] => 26
        [entity_pk_value_summary] => 1028
        [entity_type] => 1
        [reviews_count] => 1
        [rating_summary] => 100
        [store_id_summary] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [detail_id] => 1
        [review_id_detail] => 1
        [store_id_detail] => 1
        [title] => Ótimo! 
        [detail] => Adorei o buquê, muito lindo! 
        [nickname] => Débora 
        [customer_id] => 94
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [review_id] => 1
        [criadoem] => 2016-07-13 12:54:07
        [entity_id] => 1
        [entity_pk_value] => 1042
        [status_id] => 1
    )
```

)

**Segundo "giro"**

```
[0] => Array
    (
      [review_id_store] => 7 //SOMENTE ESSES VALOR É ALTERADO
      [store_id_store] => 1 //SOMENTE ESSES VALOR É ALTERADO
    )

[1] => Array
    (
      [primary_id] => 26
      [entity_pk_value_summary] => 1028
      [entity_type] => 1
      [reviews_count] => 1
      [rating_summary] => 100
      [store_id_summary] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
      [detail_id] => 1
      [review_id_detail] => 1
      [store_id_detail] => 1
      [title] => Ótimo! 
      [detail] => Adorei o buquê, muito lindo! 
      [nickname] => Débora 
      [customer_id] => 94
    )

[3] => Array
    (
      [review_id] => 1
      [criadoem] => 2016-07-13 12:54:07
      [entity_id] => 1
      [entity_pk_value] => 1042
      [status_id] => 1
    )

  )
```

Como podem ver somente os primeiros valores são alterados, depois que rodam todos os dados, cada linha (1470) ele vai para a segunda, então ele não deixa os campos nulos só que roda um de cada vez preenchendo os valores iniciais nos outros.

Comment: Você quer mudar o banco colocando todos os dados em uma única tabela, e apagando as 4 originais?

Comment: Não é necessário apagar, só gostaria de colocar os dados das 4 tabelas em outras 4

Comment: Um backup ou algo assim?

Comment: voce quer transferir os registros que ja existem em 4 tabelas para apenas uma única

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Sim, um backup só que em vez de fazer 6 scripts que na verdade são 6 tabelas eu gostaria de saber se tem como eu fazer a consulta nelas de uma vez buscando os valores que eu gostaria

Comment: @Victor Exatamente, pegar vamos supor: `Nome, Idade` da tabela `Pessoa` e pegar o `Peso, Altura` da tabela `Corpo` etc..

Comment: Algo como [SQL INSERT INTO SELECT Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)?

Comment: Isso eu consigo, mas eu teria de fazer 1 por 1, eu gostaria de fazer esses selects em varias tabelas de uma vez